# Ipad multiple detail views with navigation

Tags: iphone, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, detailview

For my ipad application i have requirement like this

For each row in root view, i want to display different detail view and

Detail view has some buttons click on it will show another view ( detailview needs to be under navigation controller)

Anyone can give me tutorial/example code/video which meets this requirement?

I have tried more than 20 similar questions here and search youtube and all but no luck.

I got one link http://kshitizghimire.com.np/uisplitviewcontroller-multipledetailviews-with-navigation-controller/ but it has some problem with pop-over is not being hidden when we select a row in portrait mode.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

PS: My requirement is something like this

```
ROOTVIEW
|— OPTION 1
|— (uinavigationcontroller)
| |OPT1_DETAILVIEW
| |– OPT1_DRILLDOWNVIEW1
| |–OPT1_DRILLDOWNVIEW2
| |–etc
|— OPTION 2
|— (uinavigationcontroller)
| |OPT2_DETAILVIEW
| |– OPT2_DRILLDOWNVIEW1
| |–etc
|— OPTION 3, etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced this problem for my project. I accomplished this using following code

What you have to do is when you tap on any cell of root view controller's tableview you have to load the appropriate viewcontroller.

The following code you have to write in tableViewDidSelectRowaAtIndexPath section of root view controller's tableview.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //Load previous controllers array.

    NSMutableArray *viewControllerArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:splitViewController.viewControllers]; 

    //Remove last Detail View controller Object.

    [viewControllerArray removeLastObject];

    // Check appropirate row value.

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        // Add new Detail controller in your array ...
        FirstViewController *fvc=[[[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController"  bundle:nil] autorelease];        
        [viewControllerArray addObject:fvc];
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        // Add new Detail controller in your array ...
        SecondViewController *svc=[[[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController"  bundle:nil] autorelease];        
        [viewControllerArray addObject:svc];
    }
    // And so on..

    // Set New View Controllers of SplitViewController

    [splitViewController setViewControllers:viewControllerArray];   
    [viewControllerArray release];      
}
```

I did that and it worked. I hope it may help.

Comment: but i think there is memory leak as objects are added continously when user taps on them
also, how to make detail view controller a Navigation based
i.e. able to push views

Comment: there may be no leaks as we are creating and releasing objects. To make navigation based detailed view you can place the UINavigationController either in NIB file or you can add it while you initializing view controller.

Comment: Create Navigation controller. UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:fvc]; [navController release];

Comment: Create Navigation controller. UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:fvc]; and add this navController to array [viewControllerArray addObject:navController]; and release it [navController release];

Comment: Thanks for Neal,
If you have time can you look http://kshitizghimire.com.np/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/MultipleDetailViewsWithNavigator.zip and tell me if this is good to use and also see if you can fix the pop-over not being hidden in detail view in that code

Comment: i checked your code it works fine. popover also being hidden while you click outside of box.

Comment: No, when you are in portrait mode and when you select a view from pop-over... detail view is being changed but pop-up is still there
I think it needs to be closed

Comment: as its default behaviour of popoverview with splitviewcontroller and you could do this by dismissing popoverview controller while selecting row.

Comment: Hey Neal, if you have time can you give me example code zip with above  written code?
I am trying to implement it but getting failed... may be different version sof xcode also may be a problem
Please send me dummy project which will be helpful to me